# How to make a WPF TextBlock spin whenever its value updates?

Tags: wpf, binding, rotation, routed-events

I'm trying to spin a TextBlock 360 degrees whenever it's binding updates.

From everything I've read the following should work, however it doesn't have any effect.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Total, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">

    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="TotalSpinTransform" Angle="0"/>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>

    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                            From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>

</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Do you see warnings in the output window when it runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `EnterActions` nor `ExitActions` are applicable to `EventTrigger`. Unfortunately, these properties are defined on `TriggerBase` so they are present on an `EventTrigger`. Try this:

```
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: Ha... I didn't even notice it was EnterAction... I just assumed Action (which is what I had in my solution) and mocked up a sample by putting it in a style instead. Good call though!